# Xamarin App crashes calling HTTPS

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, httpclient

I created a simple Xamarin.Forms App to check HTTPS using https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/.

But the App crashes using HTTPS.

```
 public RestService() {
      client = new HttpClient();
      client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
    }

public async Task<List<Item>> RefreshDataAsync() {
  string url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  // Crash using this URL
  //string url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url, string.Empty));
  List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();

  var content = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(content);

  return Items;
}
}
```

Is it a problem with the website or httpClient or do I do somethin wrong ?

Thats the Exception

```
{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.) ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00037] in <d2bf9ddce2b945f79db1e7c4354bafea>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult ar, System.Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in <d2bf9ddce2b945f79db1e7c4354bafea>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00071] in <d2bf9ddce2b945f79db1e7c4354bafea>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00032] in <d2bf9ddce2b945f79db1e7c4354bafea>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <d2bf9ddce2b945f79db1e7c4354bafea>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0004b] in <d2bf9ddce2b945f79db1e7c4354bafea>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000e] in <a547bd0d78184f26ab08d022f013c1e1>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x0000e] in <a547bd0d78184f26ab08d022f013c1e1>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MonoTlsStream.CreateStream (System.Byte[] buffer) [0x0007b] in <a547bd0d78184f26ab08d022f013c1e1>:0 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.CreateStream (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x00073] in <a547bd0d78184f26ab08d022f013c1e1>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00058] in <a547bd0d78184f26ab08d022f013c1e1>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__63.MoveNext () [0x003e6] in <b696532a7c264e5e866cb15a1b40a4a4>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__63.MoveNext () [0x00449] in <b696532a7c264e5e866cb15a1b40a4a4>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <b696532a7c264e5e866cb15a1b40a4a4>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<GetStringAsync>d__55.MoveNext () [0x0007d] in <b696532a7c264e5e866cb15a1b40a4a4>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at getWeather.RestService+<RefreshDataAsync>d__2.MoveNext () [0x0006e] in C:\Users\afelde\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\getWeather\getWeather\getWeather\RestService.cs:30 }
```

Comment: What error does it give? stacktrace?

Comment: use the debugger.

Comment: I remember reading there was problems with TLS 1.2 and mono. If you think it's the cause of your problem, give a shot to : [ModernHttpClient](https://components.xamarin.com/view/modernhttpclient). This just wrap the  Android or IOS specific http client instead. If you are on Android, you may also check the settings in you project, in Android Options, advanced, HttpClient Implementation...

Comment: In this Case this App is deployed and tested only by Anroid, the HttpClient Implementation is set to Default and SSL/TLS also. What should the settings be set  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a post about your issue (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10405/the-authentication-or-decryption-has-failed-in-the-web-request)

Here in the comments you will find someone suggesting to use the package [modernhttpclient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/modernhttpclient/)

The way to work with this package:
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());

The NativeMessagehandler will solve the certifcations issue ( since u using https it gave a authentication error, this will solve it)

For the rest you can use the client as you were already using it.

Good luck

Comment: I can't believe it works !! But is there no other way using HTTPS

Comment: @feldeOne normally this uses the HTTPS? I might be wrong but this plugin will help you with the certifcations that you need to utilize HTTPS

Answer (score 4):

That [Post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10405/the-authentication-or-decryption-has-failed-in-the-web-request) on Xamarin.Forum also solve the Issue without installing any Nuget Packages :

> As @SvetlomirKalitsov describes, the two settings below take care of
>   the issue:
>
> HttpClient implementation -> AndroidClientHandler SSL/TLS
>   implementation -> Native TLS 1Here is where I made the mistake: There
>   are two pretty similar options: Native TLS 1.2+ which is the correct
>   one, and Default (Native TLS 1.2+). This second one (Default) will
>   fail. Make sure to select the non-default one; in other words, make
>   sure to force that option instead of relying on the Default.
>
> A bit of background info: XA_HTTP_CLIENT_HANDLER_TYPE environment
>   variable on Xamarin.Android
>
> Thanks @SvetlomirKalitsov

Comment: I didn't saw that one, sorry!

Comment: It was nevertheless your post that gave me a hint ;-)