# Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a problem when I run a call to the web service iOS project, only in the production url (HTTPS). In homologation Url (HTTP) the call to the web service works perfectly, but when I switch to production url (HTTPS) the application crashes. Only iOS. My output:

> Thread finished:  #10
>   The thread 0xa has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   Thread finished:  #11
>   The thread 0xb has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   Thread finished:  #6
>   The thread 0x6 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   2018-03-28 04:34:13.362 AppNivel.iOS[4830:44384] 
>   Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (One or more errors occurred.) ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Security.Interface.TlsException: CertificateUnknown
>     at Mono.AppleTls.AppleTlsContext.EvaluateTrust () [0x000ca] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.8.0.20/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/Mono.AppleTls/AppleTlsContext.cs:269 
>     at Mono.AppleTls.AppleTlsContext.RequirePeerTrust () [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.8.0.20/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/Mono.AppleTls/AppleTlsContext.cs:210 
>     at Mono.AppleTls.AppleTlsContext.ProcessHandshake () [0x00046] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.8.0.20/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/Mon
>   o.AppleTls/AppleTlsContext.cs:186 
>     at ...
>
> at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.8.0.20/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
>     at AppNivel.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in D:\AppNivel_Bkp_14032018_1450h\AppNivel\AppNivel.iOS\Main.cs:17 
>   2018-03-28 04:34:13.366 AppNivel.iOS[4830:44384] Unhandled managed exception:
>   An error occurred while sending the request (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException)
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__64.MoveNext () [0x0046c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.8.0.20/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:406 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.8.0.20/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/msco
>   rlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.8.0.20/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
>     at ...
>
> 2018-03-28 04:34:13.401 AppNivel.iOS[4830:44384] critical:
>
> Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
>   a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
>   used by your application.
>
> The app has been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

It might cauesd by the certifcations  when using HTTPS.

You can use third-party plugin to request HTTPS.

For example, [modernhttpclient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/modernhttpclient/) , it can solve the certifcations issue.

Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44922902/8187800)