# Issue with AndroidClientHandler: is it possible to edit src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidClientHandler.cs?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm experiencing issues with AndroidClientHandler. Have added try/catch on each WebClient task but sometimes it makes app crash with exception:

```
JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallIntMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args)
Java.IO.IOException: Read error: ssl=0x79aa9b2e08: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
```

After some research, I found this thread [[AndroidClientHandler] Observe cancellation requests more #4589](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/4589), and what I understand reading this is that I need to edit src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidClientHandler.cs changing the highlighted lines as [HERE](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/commit/2acafc95eb581e17046d576eb3db51af5c8cac01) . I'm able to find AndroidClientHandler.cs but it seems to be readonly and it's really different from the file on that github url. Do I really need to edit that file? Is there a higher level workaround for this issue?

Comment: About app crash when call WebClient, I suggest you can take a look this thread;[Xamarin App crashes calling HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44922114/xamarin-app-crashes-calling-https)

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT changing WebClient by HttpClient would force me to rewrite all the code since they don't have same methods, also I'm using 3rd party nugget packages that uses HttpClient already and sometimes one of those packages(PusherClient) is the origin of the crash. So I was looking for a globally solution.

Comment: If you have better solution, please share it here.